# Net::ReadTimeout Error While Testing Rails App using cucumber, poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I am doing automation testing of a rails app. Using cucumber-rails gem, Poltergeist and Capybara gem. 
I get following error's when I run a single scenario or a complete folder of scenarios.

**Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)**

I often get  **Server out of reach error.**

Before running a scenario I change my driver with below line

```
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
```

A small example is below
   Scenario: Mark asset as Sold on Assets Page for leader
      Given javascript driver is changed
      Given "company_admin" is login
      And Create a group
      Then logout from "Company Admin"

I usually get error on company admin is login line.
Can anyone please help in fixing this error

below are the testing gems I am currently using or have in my gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'rails_dt'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem "chromedriver-helper"
  # Pry navigation commands via byebug
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0' # easy fixtures
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0' # better unit testing
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'rspec-activejob'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'valid_attribute' # concise validation testing
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'whiny_validation'
end
```

Comment: Can you give any more details about the network topography? It wasn't clear to me what server you are actually trying to connect to in this scenario. Is it a true remote server that is actually just unreliable or slow and therefore you get a timeout sometimes? Or a test server of some kind running on your localhost perhaps?

Comment: I am running tests on my local machine